# I need help writing sql to join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I see there are a few different threads here about SQL joins with three tables. I have a bit of a different issue that is giving me trouble. It may be a DB design issue or maybe I'm not using the join correctly?
I have three tables

```
artists (id, name)
contents (id, artist_id, title)
sales (id, artist_id, content_id, revenue, sales_date)
```

in my database, I want to get the **artist id**, **content id** and **sum of each artist's contents sales revenue**
below is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
       artists.id AS artist, contents.id AS artist, 
       SUM(sales.revenue)AS revenue
FROM artist_sales
       INNER JOIN contents  ON sales.content_id = contents.id
       INNER JOIN artists ON   sales.artist_id = artists.id
WHERE
    sales.artist_id = artists.id AND
    sales.content_id = contents.id AND
    sales.sales_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY artists.id;
```

the result I get is for artist first content's revenue

sample data :

### artist table [image: contents table]

### contents table[image: artists table]

### sales table[image: sales table]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It's not the "First" `content.id`. It's actually just a random one from your storage for that `artist.id` (it just happens to be "first" now but there is no guarantee it will stay that way). In fact this query would fail in mysql 5.7 or newer (unless you toggle some flags to allow old behavior). Back on topic though. You want ALL `contents.id` for each `artist.id`. Do you want the `artist_revenue` totaled for each `contents.id` for that `artist.id`, or do you want the full total `artist_revenue` for the artist repeated for each unique `contents.id`/row over and over again?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
You show us the source data but fail to show what result you want or what is your current result and why is wrong

Comment: @JNevill I want the revenue totaled for each contents.id for that artists.id.

Answer (score 0):

For start if you only want the `artist_id` you dont need a `JOIN` .

```
 SELECT artist_id, content_id, SUM(revenue)
 FROM artist_sales
 WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
 GROUP BY artist_id, content_id

 SELECT artist_id, SUM(revenue)
 FROM artist_sales
 WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
 GROUP BY artist_id
```

Now if you want the artist name or the content title you need the `JOIN` like scaisEdge show